# Auth fails when I try to log in, but the sign-up seems fine

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt, body-parser

I'm following a NodeJS, Angular and MongoDB course (I can't ask the teacher) in which I'm developing a Music Web Page / API and I'm stuck in the Sign up - Sign in part, the first one works perfectly because when I try it with Postman, all the data shows right in the database, but when I want to log in with the same data I get everytime the 402 response, although the data it's the same I used in the sign up. The password is saved as a Hash, using bcrypt, after that it's supposed to be decrypted with bcrypt.compare. Idk what could be wrong in this, I don't have much practice with these technologies but I can't find answers.

Global code:

```
'use strict'

let bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
let user = require('../models/user')
```

Sign-up code:

```js
function saveUser(req, res) {
  let usr = new user();
  //se recolectan los datos del cuerpo de la petición
  let param = req.body;

  console.log(param);
  usr.name = param.name;
  usr.surname = param.surname;
  usr.email = param.email;
  usr.role = "ROLE_USER";
  usr.image = "null";

  //saves in db
  if (param.password) {
    bcrypt.hash(usr.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
      usr.password = hash;
      if (usr.name != null && usr.surname != null && usr.email != null) {
        usr.save((err, userStored) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: "Error al guardar el usuario." });
          } else {
            if (!userStored) {
              res.status(404).send({ message: "Ha ocurrido un error" });
            } else {
              res.status(200).send({ user: userStored });
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.status(200).send({ message: "Introduce los datos que faltan." });
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(200).send({ message: "Introduce la contraseña" });
  }
}
```

Login code:

```js
function loginUser(req, res) {
  let param = req.body;

  user.findOne({ email: param.email }, (err, datos) => {
    console.log(user);
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Error en la petición." });
    } else {
      if (!datos) {
        res.status(404).send({ message: "El usuario no existe" });
      } else {
        bcrypt.compare(param.password, user.password, function(err, check) {
          if (check) {
            if (param.gethash) {
              //devolver un token de jwt
            } else {
              res.status(200).send({ hola: datos });
            }
          } else {
            res.status(402).send({ message: "Credenciales no correctas." }); //Este es el mensaje que me devuelve todo el tiempo
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: in bcrypt.bcrypt.compare  you need to use `datos.password` instead of `user.password`

Comment: Nope, it still rejects the login attempt